# Magento 2 add tab to sales order not working for Magento ver. 2.2.3

Tags: magento2

Hello i am using following code to add new tab in admin sale order view. It is working in Magento ver. 2.2.1 but not working in Magento ver. 2.2.3

app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>          
        <referenceContainer name="left">
            <referenceBlock name="sales_order_tabs">
                <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">newtab</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">VENDOR\MODULE\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Custom</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Tab/Custom.php

```
<?php

namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab;


class Custom extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    /**
     * Template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'order/view/tab/custom.phtml';

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve order model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Proposal Log');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Proposal Log');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        // For me, I wanted this tab to always show
        // You can play around with the ACL settings 
        // to selectively show later if you want
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        // For me, I wanted this tab to always show
        // You can play around with conditions to
        // show the tab later
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get Tab Class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        // I wanted mine to load via AJAX when it's selected
        // That's what this does
        return 'ajax only';
    }

    /**
     * Get Class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getClass()
    {
        return $this->getTabClass();
    }

    /**
     * Get Tab Url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        // customtab is a adminhtml router we're about to define
        // the full route can really be whatever you want
        return $this->getUrl('customtab/*/customTab', ['_current' => true]);
    }
}
```

app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/etc/routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="custom_tab" frontName="customtab">
            <module name="VENDOR_MODULE" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/CustomTab.php

```
<?php

namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CustomTab extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $layoutFactory;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory
     * @param OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
    ) {
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $coreRegistry,
            $fileFactory,
            $translateInline,
            $resultPageFactory,
            $resultJsonFactory,
            $resultLayoutFactory,
            $resultRawFactory,
            $orderManagement,
            $orderRepository,
            $logger
        );
    }

    /**
     * Generate order history for ajax request
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_initOrder();
        $layout = $this->layoutFactory->create();
        // Yes, this is the same block class that we defined in sales_order_view.xml
        $html = $layout->createBlock('VENDOR\MODULE\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Custom')
            ->toHtml();
        $this->_translateInline->processResponseBody($html);
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $resultRaw */
        $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
        $resultRaw->setContents($html);
        return $resultRaw;
    }
}
```

app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/tab/custom.phtml

```
<section class="admin__page-section custom-tab-content">
    <h1>Hello New Tab!</h1>
</section>
```

Ref. [Magento 2 add tab to sales order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160874/2582)

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed. Actually i placed following file in wrong location.

```
app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/etc/routes.xml
```

Should be at

```
app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml
```