# Magento 2 how to add custom tab in admin order view page left side

Tags: magento2, admin

Magento 2 how to add a custom tab in admin order view page left the side

Comment: HI thanks for reply i already tried that but no results ,,............

Comment: in that case, show your complete code what have you tried.

Comment: sure i have tried these links 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789216/custom-tab-on-sales-order-view
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156563/magento-2-add-tab-to-sales-order

Comment: Manashvi Birla, Piyush, Dhiren Vasoya, 7ochem, Mohit Kumar  i tried that but its not working  even in that post see commets ,,,, there are telling not working it seems